# No exchange operation in DAG while reading the csv using inferschema as true in PySpark

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am reading a csv file with below code

```
df = spark_session.read.option('header','true').option('inferSchema','true').csv('path to csv')
```

Above code is creating two jobs with one stage for each job. One job for reading the header and second one is for inferring the schema. This is I am able to understand.
Job which is reading schema is having only one stage with many task. I am not able to understand why there is only one stage.

My understanding is Spark needs to merge the schema inferred by individual task to get a final schema. This merge activity should require a exchange operation.

Can someone pls share how spark is handling this merging of schema in a single stage without exchange operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange.

Represents the shuffle i.e data movement across the cluster(Executors). It is the most expensive operation and if number of partitions is more, then the exchange of data between executors will also be more.

Inferring a schema is not this, so you do not see it. Yes, it needs to merge the defs, but that is an internal operation, but not a movement of data.

Comment: So it means schema inferred from different task is indeed getting consolidated but because this is simply metadata not the actual data, it is not falling under "EXCHANGE" category thus no new stage is getting created. Correct?

Comment: Indeed. Exchange is shuffle due to groupby, sort, repartition, etc.